# Sort within a group and add a columns indicating rows below and above

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that contains something like

`+------+--------+-----+-------+
| Team | Gender | Age | Name  |
+------+--------+-----+-------+
| A    | M      |  22 | Sam   |
| A    | F      |  25 | Annie |
| B    | M      |  33 | Fred  |
| B    | M      |  18 | James |
| A    | M      |  56 | Alan  |
| B    | F      |  28 | Julie |
| A    | M      |  33 | Greg  |
+------+--------+-----+-------+`

What I'm trying to do is first group by `Team` and `Gender` (which I have been able to do so by using: `df.groupby(['Team'], as_index=False)`

Is there a way to sort the members of the group based on their age and add extra columns in there which would indicate how many members are above any particular member and how many below?

eg:
For group 'Team A':

`+------+--------+-----+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Team | Gender | Age | Name  | M_Above | M_Below | F_Above | F_Below |
+------+--------+-----+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| A    | M      |  22 | Sam   |       0 |       2 |       0 |       1 |
| A    | F      |  25 | Annie |       1 |       2 |       0 |       0 |
| A    | M      |  33 | Greg  |       1 |       1 |       1 |       0 |
| A    | M      |  56 | Alan  |       2 |       0 |       1 |       0 |
+------+--------+-----+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply custom function `f` with `groupby` by column `Team`.

In function `f` for each row first filter above and below values by [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html), then [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) value and get values desired values by [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html). Some values are missing, so need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) and then select by `ix`:

```
def f(x):
    for i,d in x.iterrows():
        above = x.ix[:i, 'Gender'].drop(i).value_counts().reindex(['M','F'])
        below = x.ix[i:, 'Gender'].drop(i).value_counts().reindex(['M','F'])
        x.ix[i,'M_Above'] = above.ix['M']
        x.ix[i,'M_Below'] = below.ix['M']
        x.ix[i,'F_Above'] = above.ix['F']
        x.ix[i,'F_Below'] = below.ix['F']
    return x

df1 = df.groupby('Team', sort=False).apply(f).fillna(0)
#cast float to int
df1.ix[:,'M_Above':] = df1.ix[:,'M_Above':].astype(int)
print (df1)
   Age Gender   Name Team  M_Above  M_Below  F_Above  F_Below
0   22      M    Sam    A        0        2        0        1
1   25      F  Annie    A        1        2        0        0
6   33      M   Greg    A        1        1        1        0
4   56      M   Alan    A        2        0        1        0
3   18      M  James    B        0        1        0        1
5   28      F  Julie    B        1        1        0        0
2   33      M   Fred    B        1        0        1        0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Team':['A','A','B','B','A','B','A'], 'Gender':['M','F','M','M','M','F','M'],
               'Age':[22,25,33,18,56,28,33], 'Name':['Sam','Annie','Fred','James','Alan','Julie','Greg']}).sort_values(['Team','Age'])

for idx, data in df.groupby(['Team'], as_index=False):
    m_tot = data['Gender'].value_counts()[0]    # number of males in current team
    f_tot = data['Gender'].value_counts()[1]    # dido^ (females)
    m_seen = 0                                  # males seen so far for current team
    f_seen = 0                                  # dido^ (females)

    for row in data.iterrows():
        (M_Above, M_below, F_Above, F_Below) = (m_seen, m_tot-m_seen, f_seen, f_tot-f_seen)
        if row[1].Gender == 'M':
            m_seen += 1
            M_below -= 1
        else:
            f_seen += 1
            F_Below -= 1

        df.loc[row[0],'M_Above'] = M_Above
        df.loc[row[0],'M_Below'] = M_below
        df.loc[row[0],'F_Above'] = F_Above
        df.loc[row[0],'F_Below'] = F_Below
```

And it results as:

```
   Age Gender Team  M_Above  M_below  F_Above  F_Below
0   22      M    A      0.0      2.0      0.0      1.0
1   25      F    A      1.0      2.0      0.0      0.0
6   33      M    A      1.0      1.0      1.0      0.0
4   56      M    A      2.0      0.0      1.0      0.0
3   18      M    B      0.0      1.0      0.0      1.0
5   28      F    B      1.0      1.0      0.0      0.0
2   33      M    B      1.0      0.0      1.0      0.0
```

And if you wish to get the new columns as `int` (as in your example), use:

```
for new_col in ['M_Above', 'M_Below', 'F_Above', 'F_Below']:
    df[new_col] = df[new_col].astype(int)
```

Which results:

```
   Age Gender   Name Team  M_Above  M_Below  F_Above  F_Below
0   22      M    Sam    A        0        2        0        1
1   25      F  Annie    A        1        2        0        0
6   33      M   Greg    A        1        1        1        0
4   56      M   Alan    A        2        0        1        0
3   18      M  James    B        0        1        0        1
5   28      F  Julie    B        1        1        0        0
2   33      M   Fred    B        1        0        1        0
```

**EDIT:** (running times comparison)

Note that this solution is faster than using `ix` (the approved solution). Average running time (over 1000 iterations) is *~6 times faster* (which would probably matter in bigger DataFrames). Run this to check:

```
import pandas as pd
from time import time
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    for i,d in x.iterrows():
        above = x.ix[:i, 'Gender'].drop(i).value_counts().reindex(['M','F'])
        below = x.ix[i:, 'Gender'].drop(i).value_counts().reindex(['M','F'])
        x.ix[i,'M_Above'] = above.ix['M']
        x.ix[i,'M_Below'] = below.ix['M']
        x.ix[i,'F_Above'] = above.ix['F']
        x.ix[i,'F_Below'] = below.ix['F']
    return x

df = pd.DataFrame({'Team':['A','A','B','B','A','B','A'], 'Gender':['M','F','M','M','M','F','M'],
                   'Age':[22,25,33,18,56,28,33], 'Name':['Sam','Annie','Fred','James','Alan','Julie','Greg']}).sort_values(['Team','Age'])
times = []
times2 = []

for i in range(1000):
    tic = time()

    for idx, data in df.groupby(['Team'], as_index=False):
        m_tot = data['Gender'].value_counts()[0]    # number of males in current team
        f_tot = data['Gender'].value_counts()[1]    # dido^ (females)
        m_seen = 0                                  # males seen so far for current team
        f_seen = 0                                  # dido^ (females)

        for row in data.iterrows():
            (M_Above, M_below, F_Above, F_Below) = (m_seen, m_tot-m_seen, f_seen, f_tot-f_seen)
            if row[1].Gender == 'M':
                m_seen += 1
                M_below -= 1
            else:
                f_seen += 1
                F_Below -= 1

            df.loc[row[0],'M_Above'] = M_Above
            df.loc[row[0],'M_Below'] = M_below
            df.loc[row[0],'F_Above'] = F_Above
            df.loc[row[0],'F_Below'] = F_Below

    toc = time()
    times.append(toc-tic)

for i in range(1000):
    tic = time()

    df1 = df.groupby('Team', sort=False).apply(f).fillna(0)
    df1.ix[:,'M_Above':] = df1.ix[:,'M_Above':].astype(int)

    toc = time()
    times2.append(toc-tic)

print(np.mean(times))
print(np.mean(times2))
```

Results:

```
0.0163134906292  # alternative solution
0.0622982912064  # approved solution
```

Comment: I marked the other solution as the answer, but wanted to let you know that your solution worked just as well! Thank you for taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: @AlokShenoy Thanks! Note that the the solution I proposed is approx. 6 times faster, which would probably be meaningful for larger DataFrames. I edited my answer to show the time comparison.